# Can't do test query to ArangoDB with curl

Tags: curl, arangodb

1. Am I right understand, that "simple" it's DB name?
2. Why data sends as "--data-binary"?

When I execute next string `curl` does not do nothing. So I can break execution with `ctrl+c`.

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_api/testdb/all  { "collection": "cars", "skip": 0, "limit" : 1 }
```

Comment: Regarding 1: a DB in a HTTP request is specified like `/_db/database-name` ([docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpDatabase/index.html)). `/_api/simple/...` is the access path for simple query methods, so `simple` does not refer to a database, collection or document if it is preceded by `_api ` ([docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpSimpleQuery/index.html)).

Comment: Eh... it's not quite obviously when simple queries can be helpful. Maybe they are excessive?

Comment: They allow to perform basic queries without using AQL. Some don't require a JSON payload even. This makes it very easy to retrieve documents, because you don't need curl, another REST client or the Arango shell.

Comment: Correction: [simple queries](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpSimpleQuery/index.html) do need a payload, at least the collection needs to be specified. Still, it's easier to `/_api/simple/all` with payload `{"collection": "test"}` than `/_api/cursor` with payload `{"query": "FOR doc IN test RETURN doc"}` because you don't need knowledge about AQL.

Answer (score 2):

If you use "curl" with

```
--data-binary @-
```

the "@-" means, that curl reads the body from stdin. Therefore you need to type in the body. For example the

```
{ "collection": "cars", "skip": 0, "limit" : 1 }
```

and then press "ctrl-D" (under Linux). Other possibility:

```
echo '{ "collection": "cars", "skip": 0, "limit" : 1 }' | curl -X PUT --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_api/testdb/all
```

Comment: Or, if you prefer to only use `curl` and no `echo`: `curl -X PUT --data-binary '{ "collection": "cars", "skip": 0, "limit" : 1 }' --dump - http://localhost:8529/_api/testdb/allecho`

Comment: `D:\Apps\curl>curl -X PUT --data-binary '{ "collection": "cars", "skip": 0, "limit" : 1 }' --dump - http://localhost:8529/_api/testdb/allecho
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: collection
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: cars,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: skip
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 0,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: limit`

Comment: What difference between `/allecho` and `/all`?

Comment: `echo '{ "collection": "cars", "skip": 0, "limit" : 1 }' | curl -X PUT --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/testdb`

`{"error":true,"code":404,"errorNum":404,"errorMessage":"unknown path ''"}`
testdb is exists.

Comment: You need to tell it what to do: `echo '{ "collection": "cars", "skip": 0, "limit" : 1 }' | curl -X PUT --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/testdb/_api/simple/all` (note the `_api` part!). BTW: leave out the single quote marks around echo on Windows, or a syntax error `unexpected token '` will be raised.

Comment: @stj: your example doesn't work (at least on Windows), this is the only working way I found, that doesn't use echo: `curl -X PUT -d "{"""collection""": """test"""}" http://localhost:8529/_db/testdb/_api/simple/all` (single quotes around the data cause unmatched brace error, single quotes inside the payload are invalid JSON; backslash escaping is possible, but triple double quotes are nicer to read and write).

Comment: Look like variant:
`D:\Apps\curl>echo { "collection": "cars", "skip": 0, "limit" : 1 } | curl -X PUT
 --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/testdb/_api/simple/all`
work for me. It's return data from `cars` collection. But I have got question. There is curl issue, or with other tools I would have same problems? I trying to get start with curl and then to switch to native language/framework like vibed.org

Comment: Am I right understand that every DB have access method `simple/all`?

Comment: My curl example was meant to work on *nix systems. MS-DOS obviously has a different form of quoting and escaping strings, and all examples need to be adjusted for that. Regarding `/all` and `/allecho`: HTTP PUT `/_api/<databasename>/all` (as in the original example) is no valid default route, and HTTP PUT `/_api/<databasename>/allecho` is no valid default route either. There exists a default route HTTP PUT `/_db/<databasename>/_api/simple/all` however (that can be shorted to just `/_api/simple/all` when working in the `_system` database).

Comment: Regarding what routes exist: the HTTP API is document here: https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpApi/index.html - the one in question (HTTP PUT `/_api/simple/all` is on this sub page: https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpSimpleQuery/index.html

Comment: @stj why docs include information about "is no valid default route"?
docs section about collections do not include any information how to set DB name with we are working? I

Comment: The pattern for accessing a specific database applies to **all** HTTP requests made to ArangoDB and not just some. [Here's the general explanation](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpDatabase/index.html): use `/_db/<databasename>/<path>` to access `<path>` in a specific database. If you don't mind accessing the route in the default database (probably `_system`), simply use `<path>`. For example, in a database named `myDatabase` and a path named `/_api/simple/all`, the URL part will become `/_db/myDatabase/_api/simple/all`. Without the database name in front, it will simply be `/_api/simple/all`.